# How can I get images of QR Code in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, qr-code, barcode-scanner

How can I get images of QR Code in iOS?

I use the below URL for scanning but I want to store image 
[Use Demo QR Code](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/)

Comment: You can use a Core Image filter to generate QR images. See the final tip at URL: https://github.com/ShinobiControls/iOS7-day-by-day/blob/master/15-core-image-filters/15-core-image-filters.md

Comment: That is a self contained tutorial. I guess you are not familiar with `AVFoundation` framework. Whole tutorial uses `AVFoundation` to capture image and then work on it. You need to know about `AVCaptureDevice`, `AVCaptureSession`, `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` etc to understand and implement that tutorial. I encourage you to start from docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188) and look at some examples by Apple itself like [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samp